# If/else statement in playframework's view

Tags: groovy, playframework-1.x

I have a view with conditional statement like this

```
#{list items: allTasks, as: 'task'}
<div class="task grid_12">

    #{list items:allClients, as: 'client' }
        <div class="client grid_1">

            #{list items:allTasksDone, as: 'taskDone'}

                #{if task.name==taskDone.task.name && client.name ==taskDone.client.name}
                    Done
                #{/if}
                #{else}
                    Not yet
                #{/else}
            #{/list}
        </div>
    #{/list}
</div>
#{/list}
```

But the result is: if the condition is true, it show "Done Not Yet", and if the condition is false, it show "Not yet Not yet".
The result was seem double.
How to fix this?

Comment: According to the documentation, composite conditions should be wrapped in parentheses. http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/tags

Comment: I have added parentheses as ` #{if (task.name == taskDone.task.name && client.name == taskDone.client.name)}` but it still doesn't work

Comment: are you sure you are not mixing up results from different iterations of the wrapping #{list} loop. Try printing ${taskDone_index} before Done or Not Yet, and add a <br/> as well to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Palako. Yes, it's because of looping variable "taskDone". I've checked and revised my code as below and it's done:

```
<div class="task grid_24">
<div class="client grid_3">
Task/Client
</div>
#{list items:allClients, as: 'client' }
<div class="client grid_2">
${client.name} </div>
#{/list}
</div>


#{list items: allTasks, as: 'task'}
<div class="task grid_24">
    <div class="client grid_3">
        ${task.name}
    </div>

    #{list items:allClients, as: 'client' }
    %{
        i =0;
        }%
        <div class="client grid_2">
            #{list items:allTasksDone, as: 'taskDone'}

                #{if (taskDone.task == task && taskDone.client == client )}
                %{
                    i++;
                    }%
                #{/if}


            #{/list}
        <div class="taskStatus grid_2">
        #{if i>0}Done#{/if}
            #{else } Not yet#{/else}
        </div>
        </div>

    #{/list}
</div>
#{/list}
```